# Using pagination with a custom model method in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm setting up pagination to display a list of images belonging to the user in their account. This is what I have in my controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => array(
            'Image.uploaded' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

    // ...

    public function images() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Your images');

        $albums = $this->Album->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Album.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
        ));
        $this->set('albums', $albums);

        // Grab the users images
        $options['userID'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $images = $this->paginate('Image');
        $this->set('images', $images);
    }

    // ...

}
```

It works, but before I implemented this pagination I had a custom method in my `Image` model to grab the users images. Here it is:

```
public function getImages($options) {
    $params = array('conditions' => array());

    // Specific user
    if (!empty($options['userID'])) {
        array_push($params['conditions'], array('Image.user_id' => $options['userID']));
    }

    // Specific album
    if (!empty($options['albumHash'])) {
        array_push($params['conditions'], array('Album.hash' => $options['albumHash']));
    }

    // Order of images
    $params['order'] = 'Image.uploaded DESC';
    if (!empty($options['order'])) {
        $params['order'] = $options['order'];
    }

    return $this->find('all', $params);
}
```

Is there a way I can use this `getImages()` method instead of the default `paginate()`? The closest thing I can find in the documentation is "Custom Query Pagination" but I don't want to write my own queries, I just want to use the `getImages()` method. Hopefully I can do that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
//controller
$opts['userID'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
$opts['paginate'] = true;
$paginateOpts = $this->Image->getImages($opts);
$this->paginate = $paginateOpts;
$images = $this->paginate('Image');


//model
if(!empty($opts['paginate'])) {
    return $params;
} else {
    return $this->find('all', $params);
}
```

**Explanation:**

Basically, you just add another parameter (I usually just call it "paginate"), and if it's true in the model, instead of passing back the results of the find, you pass back your dynamically created parameters - which you then use to do the paginate in the controller.

This lets you continue to keep all your model/database logic within the model, and just utilize the controller to do the pagination after the model builds all the complicated parameters based on the options you send it.